# SQL expression cause ORA 00936 Missing Expression Error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssas, odac

I'm trying to add a named calculation field in ssas project, the following expression works with sql server datasource not with an oracle one :

```
convert(datetime,convert(date,DATE_HR_INSC),110)
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no `convert` function in Oracle. Since I don't know SQL Server, I don't know what your code snippet is meant to do. If you add an explanation of what you need to do, people who know Oracle but not SQL Server (like me!) will perhaps be able to help.

Comment: Well, there is a `convert` function, but it converts a string between 2 charsets, which is why it's complaining - it wants a third argument. It looks like you're trying to strip the time info from a datetime field. Just use `trunc` for that.

Comment: Basically, I want to convert the format of DATE_HR_INSC field which is in datetime to date format

Comment: Is this question for `sql server` or for `Oracle` ? Both are different databases and in both the function `convert` does something entirely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would like to convert your date value into string using format 110, which means mm-dd-yyyy (12-30-2019).

The way to do it in oracle is:

```
to_char(date,'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: OK Thank you @Michael, So I must use sql of oracle anstead of sql server !

Answer (score 1):

The first inner step of this SQL Server code is casting `DATE_HR_INSC` to a date.  Then, this is being converted to a datetime with format mask `110`.  I'm not sure this makes sense, and I would instead have expected to see the following:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DATE_HR_INSC), 110)
```

This would have generated a datetime with the format `mm-dd-yyyy`.  We can try to approximate this in Oracle using the `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` functions.  Something like this:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE_HR_INSC, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

### Demo

This assumes that `DATE_HR_INSC` is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.  If its format is something else, then replace the mask used in the call to `TO_DATE` above.